# Function to obtain chr info

Tags: r, syntax, bioconductor

I am trying to make a function to obtain the size for a given chr in a given genome. Follows what I have tried so far.

```
chrx <- as.character("chr1")
Bchrs <- function(x){
  library(BSgenome.Ggallus.UCSC.galGal4)
  genome <- BSgenome.Ggallus.UCSC.galGal4
  boundaries <- NULL
  boundaries$Chrl <- length(genome$x)
  boundaries$Chrn <- 'x'
  return(boundaries)
}
```

What I could expect using this function is:

```
chrx <- "chr1" 
Bchrs(chrx)
```

> $Chrl [1] 195276750
>
> $Chrn [1] "chr1"

However I am getting this error:

```
Bchrs(chrx)
```

> Error in x[[name]] : no such sequence

I will be grateful for any light to make it works.

Comment: Use `[[` instead of `$` inside a function to extract the columns i.e. `length(genome[[x]])`  Also, I think `boundaries$Chrn <- 'x'` is not doing what you expect. The quotes are not needed.

Comment: also, you should try an example _before_ writing a function

Comment: I guess you're the same person as [here](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/77913/); the length of some chromeomse `x = "chr1"` is `seqlengths(BSgenome.Ggallus.UCSC.galGal4)[[x]]`.